# Как подключить и использовать swc библиотеку в Flex Builder?

Tags: flash, actionscript, swf, apache-flex

Как использовать в коде actionscript анимации из Flash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кликнете на проект, открывается меню, там выбираете свойства (properties), в открывшемся окне выбираете вкладку actionscript build path, там будет кнопка add swc. В ней надо будет указать путь до swc.

Для запуска анимации из `swc` убедитесь, что анимации в библиотеке имеет название класса (ClassName). А в проекте потом после прилинковки swc надо будет написать.

```
var movie:MovieClip = new ClassName;
this.addChild(movie);
movie.play();
```